# Java - How to check if value of an array contains specified value as attribute

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have an array of Player objects.
The players have names and when i add a player, i want to check if the playername already exists. Following code never throws the exception, it just adds duplicate players.

```
public void addPlayer(String name, boolean gender, int index)  throws RuntimeException {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

    if (names.contains(name))
        throw new DuplicatePlayerException();
    else {
        players[index] = new Player(name, gender);
        names.add(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is players[index]?

Comment: issue in this line   List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(); every time you create new ArrayList.

Comment: Because every time you create new `List<String> names` which is empty. It should be a `class-level-variable`

Comment: Using a `boolean` for gender is somehow from the last century... `names` cannot contain the given name in the method because it will always be empty before your `if` statement that checks if the name is contained. Make it a class attribute...

Answer (score 9):

```
public void addPlayer(String name, boolean gender, int index)  throws RuntimeException {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(); // you create a new instance of the list each time you call it, so it'll always be empty

    if (names.contains(name)) // your empty list does not contain anything
        throw new DuplicatePlayerException();
    else {
        players[index] = new Player(name, gender);
        names.add(name);
    }
}
```

You'll need to change your method, to work with an instance level list:

```
private List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
public void addPlayer(String name, boolean gender, int index)  throws RuntimeException {
    if (names.contains(name))
        throw new DuplicatePlayerException();
    else {
        players[index] = new Player(name, gender);
        names.add(name);
    }
}
```

so the contents of `names` won't be erased each time you call your method.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider `Set<Player>` instead of array. `Set` by definition can not contain the duplicates. Assuming `Player` has implemented `equals/hashcode` your code might look like:

```
Set<Player> players = new HashSet<>();

public void addPlayer(Player player)  throws RuntimeException {
    if (!players.add(player)) {
        throw new DuplicatePlayerException();
    }
}
```

[`Set::add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add-E-) returns true if the set did not already contain the element

Comment: even though this is indeed a good remark, if he had used a Set instead of a List, he still would have had the same problem

Comment: @Stultuske I suggest to use Set instead of array. There is no List in my answer

Comment: I was referring to the code of the OP, where he used a list. In your answer, you fixed his error, yet you don't speak of that, you only explain the benefit of using a Set (after fixing his error)

Answer (score 0):

```
String Names = "John";
    if (Names.toLowerCase().contains("john")){
        System.out.println("yes");
    }
```

You can also use .toLowerCase().contains() to include case sensitive inputs.

Comment: This would make a good comment, but it is not related to the actual problem the OP encountered.